# How to create a dynamic form in a ng for with angular to post data to a database?

Tags: angular

I'm making a web application that reads questions from a database and prints them, then asks the user to input the answers.

Using an ng for in the html to iterate over the database and print the questions. Tried using formgroups but getting errors i don't know how to fix

```
HTML:
<form id="myForm" [formGroup]="thisIsMyForm">
    <div [formArrayName] = "'formArrayName'">
        <ul *ngFor="let question of questions[0]; let i = index">
            <div formGroupName="{{i+1}}">
                <div *ngIf="question.Capability === Capability">
                    <h3 class="SubCat">{{question.SubCategory}} {{question.Skill}}</h3>
                        <div class="EandS">
                            <h4 class="skill">Skill</h4>
                            <h4 class="energy">Energy</h4>
                        </div>


                        <div class = "buttons">
                            <div class="skillButtons">
                                <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select your Skill Level" >
                                        <mat-radio-button  value="0" class="rbuttonSkill">0</mat-radio-button>
                                        <mat-radio-button  value="1" class="rbuttonSkill">1</mat-radio-button>
                                        <mat-radio-button  value="2" class="rbuttonSkill">2</mat-radio-button>
                                        <mat-radio-button  value="3" class="rbuttonSkill" >3</mat-radio-button>
                                        <mat-radio-button  value="4" class="rbuttonSkill" >4</mat-radio-button>
                                </mat-radio-group>
                            </div>

                        <div class="energyButtons">
                            <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select your Energy Level" >
                                    <mat-radio-button  value="1" class="rbuttonEnergy" >1</mat-radio-button>
                                    <mat-radio-button  value="2" class="rbuttonEnergy" >2</mat-radio-button>
                                    <mat-radio-button  value="3" class="rbuttonEnergy" >3</mat-radio-button>
                            </mat-radio-group>
                            <button *ngIf="!fomrControlState(i)" (click)="toggleEdit(i)">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button [disabled]="thisIsMyForm.get('formArrayName').enabled" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit Form</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div> 
</form>


TS: 


export class QuestionListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
    questions: Question[] = [];
    private questionsSub: Subscription;
    thisIsMyForm: FormGroup

    @Input() Capability: string;
    constructor(public questionsService: QuestionService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder){
        this.thisIsMyForm = new FormGroup ({
            formArrayName: this.formBuilder.array([])
        })
        this.buildForm();
    }

    buildForm(){
        const controlArray = this.thisIsMyForm.get('formArrayName') as FormArray;

        Object.keys(this.questions).forEach((i) => {
            controlArray.push(
                this.formBuilder.group({
                    Capability: new FormControl({value: this.questions[i].Capability, disabled:true }),
                    SubCategory: new FormControl({value: this.questions[i].SubCategory, disabled: true}),
                    Skill: new FormControl({value: this.questions[i].Skill, disabled:true}),
                    SkillID: new FormControl({value: this.questions[i].SkillID, disabled:true})
                })
            )
        })
        console.log(controlArray)
    }

    toggleEdit(i){
        const controlArray = this.thisIsMyForm.get('formArrayName') as FormArray;
        if(controlArray.controls[i].status === 'DISABLED'){
            controlArray.controls[i].enable()
        }else{
            controlArray.controls[i].disable()
        }
    }

    fomrControlState(i){
        const controlArray = this.thisIsMyForm.get('formArrayNAme') as FormArray;
        return controlArray.controls[i].disable
    }


    ngOnInit(){
        this.questionsService.getQuestions().subscribe(
            data => {
            this.questions = [];
            Object.keys(data).map((key)=>{ this.questions.push(data[key]) });
            console.log(this.questions);
            });

    }
    onSubmit(){
        console.log(this.thisIsMyForm.value)
    }
}
```

Need to get a JSON with all the scores of the questions with their skillID

Comment: Hi Luke. Welcome to StackOverflow. Would you please share some sample data to work with?

Comment: "userdata": [
        {
            "Capability": "Associate",
            "SubCategory": "Core Skills",
            "Skill": "Communication",
            "SkillID": 1
        },
        {
            "Capability": "Associate",
            "SubCategory": "Core Skills",
            "Skill": "Organisation Skills",
            "SkillID": 2
        },

Answer (score 1):

You should be creating a `FormArray` once the data has been retrieved from the API. Each item in the `Capabilities` array can be mapped into a `FormGroup`. You can then bind it to the `form` HTMLElement.

You'll also need a method to enable or disable a particular Capability `FormGroup`

Here give this a try:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  capabilityForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('/assets/data.json')
      .subscribe((data: any[]) => {
        this.capabilityForm = this.fb.group({
          capabilities: this.fb.array(data.map(datum => this.generateDatumFormGroup(datum)))
        });
      });
  }

  enableSection(index, disabled) {
    const capabilityFormGroup = (<FormArray>this.capabilityForm.get('capabilities')).at(index);
    disabled ? capabilityFormGroup.enable() : capabilityFormGroup.disable();
  }

  private generateDatumFormGroup(datum) {
    return this.fb.group({
      capability: this.fb.control({ value: datum.Capability, disabled: true }),
      subCategory: this.fb.control({ value: datum.SubCategory, disabled: true }),
      skill: this.fb.control({ value: datum.Skill, disabled: true }),
      skillId: this.fb.control({ value: datum.SkillID, disabled: true })
    });
  }

}
```

And in the template:

```
<form 
  *ngIf="capabilityForm"
  [formGroup]="capabilityForm">
  <div formArrayName="capabilities">
    <div *ngFor="let capability of capabilityForm.controls['capabilities'].controls; let i = index">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <input type="text" formControlName="capability">
        <input type="text" formControlName="subCategory">
        <input type="text" formControlName="skill">
        <input type="text" formControlName="skillId">
        <button (click)="enableSection(i, capability.disabled)">{{ capability.disabled ? 'Edit': 'Save' }}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

**PS:** I've not used Angular Material in the template. Please do that yourself.

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-data-from-api-and-populate-form-array-with-it?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: @LukeHarland, your sample data doesn't have skill level and enery level. Hence no mention of that in the stackblitz. Plus, please feel free to fork the provided stackblitz, reproduce your issue and share it across so that I could have a look. Plus dealing with radio button would just be similar to that of dealing with a regular text field as the value is what is binded.